# C# publish application properties

Tags: c#, publish

I want to publish a desktop application in C#,
I created a setup project and every thing is ok but I can not find where to:

1. Modify the name of the program folder which is now: 'Default Company Name'.
2. How can I force it to show a desktop short cut.

Comment: I created a setup project but I didn't find where to control these two points

Comment: after setup project craeted and while running your application,it will automatically ask for creating desktop shortcut.

Comment: You have create a new folder named your company name in the registry of setup process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Modify the name of the program folder which is now: 'Default Company Name'.

click on Setup solution then press F4 , or get properties menu you will find the Author / Manufacturer / ... with 'Default Company Name' so change them with whatever you want

> How can I force it to show a desktop short cut.

right click on solution -> view -> File System

choose Application Folder then right click on the files that you wish to create shortcut on desktop then choose 'Create Shortcut to ........'

then go to User's desktop and rename the shortcut (remove Shortcut word from the shortcut name)

Answer (score 0):

You should check in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the main project or in the Project Properties of the Setup Project.